# How can I control this code with "setInterval"?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, telegram, setinterval

I tried create a function for use that code in setInterval but when I create a function with that code it stop working. I tried almost everything. Could you guys help me about that?

```
(async () => {

  let feed = await parser.parseURL(url);


    
  feed.items.forEach(item => {
       const habert = item.pubDate;
       const d2 = new Date(habert)
     
       var diffMs = (d1 - d2);
       var diffHrs = Math.floor((diffMs % 86400000) / 3600000); // hours
       var diffMins = Math.round(((diffMs % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000); // minutes
       
       if(diffMins <= 5 && diffHrs <= 0){
            //console.log(` Yeni haber geldi: `+'\n'+"Başlık: "+ item.title+`\n`+"İçerik: "+ item.content+ "İçerik sisteme kayıt edildi."+ `\n`+ item.pubDate)
            const haber_baslik = item.title;
            console.log(haber_baslik);
            if(db.get('sonhaber') != haber_baslik){
              db.set('sonhaber', haber_baslik);
            
              bot.sendMessage('@borugazetesi', ` : ${item.title} \n \n  ${item.content}`);
              
            }else{
              return console.log("Son haber zaten sorunsuz bir şekilde gönderildi.");
          }
           //console.log(sorgu);
          }
           
          
  
  });

//setInterval(haberkontrol, 600);

})();
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to do, what is it doing and what is not working?

Comment: It's getting data from RSS ( let feed = await parser.parseURL(url); ) then It checks if the latest data if not exists in database it puts in database and sending message to Telegram channel. But I have to check every the RSS for get the latest News per seconds/minute..

Comment: is this habercontrol function?

Comment: @VelatNecmettinKanat It was but It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not defined your function properly and you are calling setInterval in the function that you call in set interval.

Can you try this? I hope it will work but I think it is not efficient to check all records for each second.

```
const habercontrol =  () => {

   parser.parseURL(url).then((feed)=>{

      
        feed.items.forEach(item => {
            const habert = item.pubDate;
            const d2 = new Date(habert)
          
            var diffMs = (d1 - d2);
            var diffHrs = Math.floor((diffMs % 86400000) / 3600000); // hours
            var diffMins = Math.round(((diffMs % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000); // minutes
            
            if(diffMins <= 5 && diffHrs <= 0){
                 //console.log(` Yeni haber geldi: `+'\n'+"Başlık: "+ item.title+`\n`+"İçerik: "+ item.content+ "İçerik sisteme kayıt edildi."+ `\n`+ item.pubDate)
                 const haber_baslik = item.title;
                 console.log(haber_baslik);
                 if(db.get('sonhaber') != haber_baslik){
                   db.set('sonhaber', haber_baslik);
                 
                   bot.sendMessage('@borugazetesi', ` : ${item.title} \n \n  ${item.content}`);
                   
                 }else{
                   return console.log("Son haber zaten sorunsuz bir şekilde gönderildi.");
               }
                //console.log(sorgu);
               }
       });


    });
  
  
  };
  
  setInterval(habercontrol, 600);
```

Comment: I tried that code you just shared but this time the code doesn't even run at the beginning. I just tried write "console.log("test message") above the "const habercontrol" the "console.log" works but the "const habercontrol" is not.

Comment: Maybe the error is related to async function and setInterval . I edited the source code in the answer. Can you try it?